# Our Greatest Hits

Tags: discussion

StackExchange, inc. added today a [new feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/): the [greatest hits](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) page.

The list is *for us* to have a convenient starting point for questions that potentially need improving since they are visited often.

That page *contains our most important questions*. They are the pages that bring in most new users, and show them what Skeptics is about. Thus, if they are not so good, those users will either leave, or get the wrong impression on the site!

[image: Go Away]

Thus, they have to be as good as possible! For example, *its imortant 2 make shur* that we avoid spelling mistakes, bad grammar, &c. Furthermore, we should either reference or delete unreferenced answers.

In other words

> There should be no broken windows, only wonderful examples of our community at its best!

[image: Come in]

Here's how *you can help* make the site better:

- Go through the [greatest hits](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) page (better if a bit randomly) and edit out any typos, bad formatting, imperfections
- Flag or fix bad answers

I am sure we can make a very positive difference on the site!

---

<sup>[Mat image source](http://trendsupdates.com/doormat-which-shows-how-social-you-are/)</sup>

Comment: Uh, where is the page actually linked? I didn’t realise it had been rolled out and I’m still unable to find any mention of it, let alone a link.

Comment: @KonradRudolph http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/

Comment: No new user ever visits the blog. The “greatest hits” so far have zero visibility, as far as I can see.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure. The questions in that list are still the most visited/relevant questions on the site. People massively visit *the questions in the list*, but not the greatest hits page :-)

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now. The list is *for us* to have a convenient starting point for questions that potentially need improving since they are visited often.

Comment: @KonradRudolph exactly. I hope you don't mind if I steal your sentence :-)

Comment: [shameless copy: Stackexchange sites should generally be opposed to bloat. That is one reason why there is general consensus greetings should be omitted or removed.](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/357/266)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange questions with no answer appear on an "Unanswered" list to attract more attention to them.

In meta-sites, like this one, sometimes questions, like this one, aren't really questions, and don't need this attention.

They are sometimes given fake answers, like this one, just so they don't appear on the "Unanswered" list.